# How to use wireless router (tp-link archer c7) as Wi-Fi to ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a wireless network in my apartment and a spare TP-Link Archer C7 wireless router.

I have a few devices that have to be connected via ethernet (Hue smart light bridge, for example). Connecting these devices via ethernet to the other router (the one that provides the wireless network) is not an option for me.

How do I use my wireless router (tp-link archer c7) as Wi-Fi to ethernet adapter? Essentially, I want to configure my router to work like one of [these devices](https://www.amazon.ca/NETGEAR-Universal-Ethernet-Adapter-WNCE3001/dp/B005N6XBDO).

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You must configure the Archer's WLAN as client (station) instead of access point (AP), and then either do NAT (network address translation) between the Archer's LAN devices and the WLAN, or enable WDS/4-address-mode on all devices of your wireless network, so you can bridge the Archer's LAN and WLAN.

I don't have any Archer C7, so I don't know how to configure that in the TP-Link firmware, or if it is possible to configure that in the TP-Link web interface at all. If it isn't, you can flash [OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c5-c7-wdr7500) onto your Archer, and use e.g. [this recipe](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/atheroswds) (with appropriate changes depending on the configuration of your main router).