# C2100T Modem/Router as Repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, repeater

I have an Asus RT-AC66U router, which is able to connect directly to the access point for my fiber internet connection.  Additionally, I have a Technicolor C2100T combined modem/router that I was required to purchase from my ISP and is currently not being used.

Is it possible to configure the C2100T to be used as a wireless repeater, either with the stock or third-party firmware?

It is my understanding that the Asus router is better and should therefore provide the source signal.

Comment: See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1262896/how-to-use-wireless-router-tp-link-archer-c7-as-wi-fi-to-ethernet-adapter/1262923#1262923) for a similar question. Try to set this up with the Technicolor stock firmware, if that's not possible, try to install OpenWRT.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same question and landed here.

I've had an AC68U that I owned before signing with my current ISP. I use the AC68U as a primary and the C2100T as a repeater for the second story.

To set up the C2100T as a repeater, you have to adjust the WAN settings (Advanced Settings > WAN Settings) and enable Transparent Bridging:

KB Article: http://internethelp.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-c2100z-adv-wan-settings.html#
Video how to as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6j-oqwRZ4ss

A good overview of network bridging: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nTgQQbF9zo

Comment: When you did it, did you select untagged or Tagged-201?  The first video suggests untagged, but http://internethelp.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-c2100t-adv-bridging-q.html suggests Tagged-201.

Is there a way to verify it is working properly, or is it just best to go far away from the primary router and do a speed test with and without the transparent bridging enabled?

Comment: I believe it was tagged-201

For testing, I had a benchmark series of tests far from the router, where I was initially receiving ~10% signal and compared with results in the same location after setting up the bridge. Now I have closer to 70% signal, and palatable speeds.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a repeater / bridge setup, this is an alternative solution to have two routers on the same network. It worked out better than a bridge setup for me:

https://youtu.be/J5QJb3O19zI

In my home network, I have an older router that maintains the connection to the ISP, and a newer router that's used for wifi. I've put them on separate channels (1 and 6 respectively), and then stopped broadcasting the SSID name for the older router. It's proved effective thus far.