# How to turn a CenturyLink C2100T Gateway into router only

Tags: networking, router

I just recently got cable internet from Spectrum and so far I haven't had a great experience. Their modem is an Arris [TM1602](https://arris.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#30000000kUAL/a/a00000009iMg/2hLRjib9gv2vCcIUNdNPzCS33zkEMYP62trT9WjpYV4=), and the router provided is a 'Spectrum' branded [RAC2V25](https://www.spectrum.net/support/internet/spectrum-wave-2-router-user-manual).

My problem lies with the router; it's a piece of crap. There are very few configurable settings, and when you do find ones to change it says there's an error. It has a one user limit on the admin panel, which is utterly broken and will kick that only person accessing out.

From when I had DSL, I had a CenturyLink 'Technicolor' [C2100T](https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/modems-and-routers/technicolor-c2100t.html) Modem/router combo. It has a coax port, but doesn't support Spectrum as a provider.

I've tried finding a way to use that C2100T as the router because it's significantly better, but the only data I found is a [reddit thread explaining  nothing](https://www.reddit.com/r/centurylink/comments/7a0w2k/technicolorcenturylink_c2100t_as_router_only/).

How can I switch the C2100T over to function as only a router to replace the 'Spectrum' RAC2V25 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C2100T Modem/Router as Repeater](https://superuser.com/questions/1263240/c2100t-modem-router-as-repeater)

Comment: No, I've looked at that thread already, there was nothing helpful.

Comment: Did you set up Transparent Bridging:in  WAN settings (Advanced Settings > WAN Settings) ?

Comment: I have. Any combination of settings don't seem to work, the router says its connected but I can't access the internet.

Comment: Since I got the router it's never had a firmware update, I'm not sure it was ever intended to serve this purpose in the first place.

Comment: Since it worked in the aforemented post, perhaps CLink changed the firmware from the version successfully used by that poster (intentionally or not) to a different release in yours, which blocks you from reusing their device. You may need to sell it and use the funds to get another router.

Comment: Please be aware that the Arris TM1602 is on the badmodems.com list of known-bad modems based on the crappy Intel Puma 6 chipset that has unfixable latency problems. You definitely want to replace that modem with something that's not based on Intel Puma 6.

Comment: @Spiff Great -_-
Thanks for the heads up.